# How to configure AWX to authenticate against OpenLDAP

Tags: authentication, openldap, ansible-awx

I am trying to configure Ansible AWX to use my ldap server to authentication.

I can use `ldapsearch` to query my ldap server like so ...

```
ldapsearch -H ldaps://ldap.example.com -D "cn=Manager,dc=example,dc=com" -W -b "dc=example.com"
```

And, of course, I had replaced `example.com` with my domain.

I also have an AWX (Opensource version of Ansible Tower).  I am trying to configure my AWX to use my ldap server for authentication.  So I logon to the AWC Web UI and go to settings and start fillout of the form for LDAP Auth:

```
LDAP Server URI: ldaps://ldap.example.com:636
LDAP Bind DN: cn=Manager,dc=example,dc=com
LDAP Bind Password: XXXXXXXXX
LDAP User DN Template: uid="%(user)s",dc=example,dc=com
LDAP Group Type: PosixUIDGroupType
```

I have no idea and I am just guessing at what I need to use for `LDAP User DN Template` or `LDAP Group Type`.

No matter what I have tried I cannot authenticate against my LDAP server :(

Answer (score 0):

I manage these via api/json, here is example:

```
   "AUTH_LDAP_USER_SEARCH": [
        "dc=example,dc=com",
        "SCOPE_SUBTREE",
        "(sAMAccountName=%(user)s)"
    ],
    "AUTH_LDAP_USER_DN_TEMPLATE": null,
    "AUTH_LDAP_USER_ATTR_MAP": {
        "first_name": "givenName",
        "last_name": "sn",
        "email": "mail"
    },
    "AUTH_LDAP_GROUP_SEARCH": [
        "dc=example,dc=com",
        "SCOPE_SUBTREE",
        "(objectClass=group)"
```

Comment: That didn't work for me. How are you using api/json to manage your ldap auth?